# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS update problem

Tags: updates

i have dual boot with Windows 10 Pro and Ubuntu Linux 16.04 LTS, I'd like to update to 18.04 but it doesn't work with the updater assistant, neither with the console; so, what can I do?

Comment: It is unlikely anyone will be able to help unless you provide more details about exactly what went wrong.

Comment: Read the messages/logs and they should tell or point you to the problem.  Usually it's packages you've added from unofficial (3rd party ppa's etc) sources that conflict, which if removed the upgrade will proceed.  We cannot see the logs/messages unless you provide them.